# Google Maps API not displaying the map after following the steps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google maps api:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?_ga=2.192156522.1955755213.1592725672-591919557.1592514255

and I have copy pasted the following code into my index.html, and added my API key in the appropriate place.

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      (function(exports) {
        "use strict";

        function initMap() {
          exports.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: {
              lat: -34.397,
              lng: 150.644
            },
            zoom: 8
          });
        }

        exports.initMap = initMap;
      })((this.window = this.window || {}));
    </script>
```

Yet, the map doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

I also see the following in the console that might be relevant:

Unhandled Promise Rejection: InvalidValueError: Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null.

But I do see the div in the dom:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't include the `<div id="map"></div>`.  If I add it (and add google's test key), it works: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ch0s5mg9/).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I´m having the same problem. Any solution?